# Is it possible to print a float with user-defined precision after decimal point in C?

Tags: c, floating-point-precision

I want to print out a float with a user-defined precision after decimal point in C, like say,

```
int dec;
float no;
printf("\nEnter no of decimal places and the number ");
scanf("%d%f",&dec,&no);
```

Then print the number `no` with `dec` decimal places.

Comment: Why post the question if you know the answer?

Comment: @ChrisDodd: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132887

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do

```
int dec;
float no;
printf("\nEnter no of decimal places and the number ");
scanf("%d%f",&dec,&no);
printf("%.*f",dec,no);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may format the printing of a floating point number, but not its actual size.

You may read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) on formatting floating point number.

To save your time, you may use the %f format specifier, as

```
printf("%.PRECISIONf", fvar);
```

where PRECISION is the number of digits you want after decimal, for e.g.

```
int 
print_float(float fvar, unsigned int precision) {
  char fs[32];
  sprintf(fs,"%%.%df", precision);
  return printf(fs, fvar);
}
```

On calling the routine:

```
print_float(2.0f, 2);
```

you will get 2.00 as the output.

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: I did format the number of decimal places I want to print for a number, using `printf("%.*f",dec,no);` where `dec` stores number of decimal places to print.

Comment: @nisargshah95 Have you got what you neeeded ? I have updated the answer.

Comment: Yes. I posted it as an answer.

Comment: Your code gives me error -
`warning: conversion lacks type at end of format [-Wformat=]` for the line
`sprintf(fs,"\%.%df",precision);`

Comment: @nisargshah95 I have fixed the issue there was a small typo, i would like to mention that, this is not the best code to do what you want, its just directional.